# Getting ActionView::Template::Error error when trying to make Rails Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, controller

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  In my “app/controllers/user_objects_controller.rb” controller file, I have defined this method …

```
  def find_totals
    respond_to do |format|
      @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
      format.json {
        @month_total = UserObject.find_total_by_user_object_month_and_year(session["user_id"], params[:object], params[:month], params[:year])
        @year_total = UserObject.find_total_by_user_object_and_year(session["user_id"], params[:object], params[:year])
        render :json => {:month => @monthTotal,
                                  :year => @yearTotal }
      }
    end
  end
```

I’m trying to use Ajax to invoke this method, and so in my “./app/assets/javascripts/user_objects.js.coffee” script, I have

```
updateTotal = (arg) ->
  object = $('#user_object_object').val()
  date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate')
  day = $('#user_object_day').val()
  month = date.getMonth() + 1
  year =  date.getFullYear()
  if (object != "" && day != "")
    # Populate the month and year totals
    $.ajax
      url: "/user_objects/find_totals"
      type: 'GET'
      data: {month: month, year: year, object: object}
      success: (data) ->
        alert(data);
        $('#month_total').val(data)
        $('#year_total').val(data)
      error: ->
        alert "Something went wrong getting month and year total"
```

but I always get the error condition.  In my Rails server the below log is printed:

```
D, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475092 #12929] DEBUG -- : 
D, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475206 #12929] DEBUG -- : 
D, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475236 #12929] DEBUG -- : 
D, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475265 #12929] DEBUG -- : 
I, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475505 #12929]  INFO -- : Started GET "/user_objects/find_totals?month=2&year=2016&object=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-24 15:42:24 -0600
I, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.475539 #12929]  INFO -- : Started GET "/user_objects/find_totals?month=2&year=2016&object=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-24 15:42:24 -0600
F, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.500710 #12929] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `object' for nil:NilClass):
    2: 
    3: <p>
    4:   <strong>object:</strong>
    5:   <%= @user_object.object %>
    6: </p>
    7: 
    8: <p>
  app/views/user_objects/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_user_objects_show_html_erb__2677150194333288712_70363943163180'


F, [2016-02-24T15:42:24.500751 #12929] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `object' for nil:NilClass):
    2: 
    3: <p>
    4:   <strong>object:</strong>
    5:   <%= @user_object.object %>
    6: </p>
    7: 
    8: <p>
  app/views/user_objects/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_user_objects_show_html_erb__2677150194333288712_70363943163180'
```

Anyone know what this error means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Rails is trying to render show.html.erb, which implies that the ajax request is hitting the show action on your UserObjects controller, which would be indicative of incorrect routes.

Check your routes file. Routes are matched in the order they're specified, so if you have `resources :user_objects` before you have something like `get "user_objects/find_totals" ...` then Rails will think the "user_objects/find_totals" URL matches to the show action on your UserObjects controller, with an id of `find_totals`.

Comment: Yup, adding a "get :find_totals, on: :collection" into my routes.rb "resources :user_objects do" section solved it.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `object' for nil:NilClass

means that `@user_object` here

```
<%= @user_object.object %>
```

is nil. Which makes sense given that `@user_object` is no where to be found in your controller method/action `def find_totals`

You will need to set that instance variable somewhere in your controller for it to be available for you in your view

Answer (score 0):

@user_object is nil.

undefined method `object' for nil:NilClass